# golang doing unexpected heap memory allocation

Tags: go, assembly, delve

While benchmarking, I noticed a surprising heap memory allocation. After reducing the repro, I ended up with the following:

```
// --- Repro file ---
func memAllocRepro(values []int) *[]int {

  for {
        break
    }

    return &values
}

// --- Benchmark file ---
func BenchmarkMemAlloc(b *testing.B) {

    values := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        memAllocRepro(values)
    }
}
```

And here is the benchmark output:

```
BenchmarkMemAlloc-4     50000000            40.2 ns/op        32 B/op          1 allocs/op
PASS
ok      memalloc_debugging  2.113s
Success: Benchmarks passed.
```

Now the funny this is, if I remove the for loop, or if I return the slice directly instead of a slice pointer, there are no more heap alloc:

```
// --- Repro file ---
func noAlloc1(values []int) *[]int {

    return &values // No alloc!
}

func noAlloc2(values []int) []int {
  for {
        break
    }

    return values // No alloc!
}

// --- Benchmark file ---
func BenchmarkNoAlloc(b *testing.B) {

    values := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        noAlloc1(values)
        noAlloc2(values)
    }
```

Benchmark result:

```
BenchmarkNoAlloc-4      300000000            4.20 ns/op        0 B/op          0 allocs/op
PASS
ok      memalloc_debugging  1.756s
Success: Benchmarks passed.
```

I found that very confusing and confirmed with Delve that the disassembly does has an allocation at the start of the memAllocRepro function:

```
(dlv) disassemble
TEXT main.memAllocRepro(SB) memalloc_debugging/main.go
        main.go:10      0x44ce10        65488b0c2528000000      mov rcx, qword ptr gs:[0x28]
        main.go:10      0x44ce19        488b8900000000          mov rcx, qword ptr [rcx]
        main.go:10      0x44ce20        483b6110                cmp rsp, qword ptr [rcx+0x10]
        main.go:10      0x44ce24        7662                    jbe 0x44ce88
        main.go:10      0x44ce26        4883ec18                sub rsp, 0x18
        main.go:10      0x44ce2a        48896c2410              mov qword ptr [rsp+0x10], rbp
        main.go:10      0x44ce2f        488d6c2410              lea rbp, ptr [rsp+0x10]
        main.go:10      0x44ce34        488d0525880000          lea rax, ptr [rip+0x8825]
        main.go:10      0x44ce3b        48890424                mov qword ptr [rsp], rax
=>      main.go:10      0x44ce3f*       e8bcebfbff              call 0x40ba00 runtime.newobject
```

I must say though, once I hit that point, I couldn't easily dig further. I'm pretty sure it would be possible to know at least which type is allocated by looking at the structure pointed to by the RAX register, but I wasn't very successful doing so. It's been a long time since I've read disassembly like this.

```
(dlv) regs
   Rip = 0x000000000044ce3f
   Rsp = 0x000000c042039f30
   Rax = 0x0000000000455660
   (...)
```

All that being said, I have 2 questions: 
* Anyone can tell why is there a heap allocation there and if it's "expected"? 
* How could I have gone further in my debugging session? Dumping memory to hex has a different address layout and go tool objdump will output disassembly, which mangle the content at the address location

Full function dump with go tool objdump:

```
TEXT main.memAllocRepro(SB) memalloc_debugging/main.go
  main.go:10        0x44ce10        65488b0c2528000000  MOVQ GS:0x28, CX            
  main.go:10        0x44ce19        488b8900000000      MOVQ 0(CX), CX              
  main.go:10        0x44ce20        483b6110        CMPQ 0x10(CX), SP           
  main.go:10        0x44ce24        7662            JBE 0x44ce88                
  main.go:10        0x44ce26        4883ec18        SUBQ $0x18, SP              
  main.go:10        0x44ce2a        48896c2410      MOVQ BP, 0x10(SP)           
  main.go:10        0x44ce2f        488d6c2410      LEAQ 0x10(SP), BP           
  main.go:10        0x44ce34        488d0525880000      LEAQ runtime.types+34656(SB), AX    
  main.go:10        0x44ce3b        48890424        MOVQ AX, 0(SP)              
  main.go:10        0x44ce3f        e8bcebfbff      CALL runtime.newobject(SB)      
  main.go:10        0x44ce44        488b7c2408      MOVQ 0x8(SP), DI            
  main.go:10        0x44ce49        488b442428      MOVQ 0x28(SP), AX           
  main.go:10        0x44ce4e        48894708        MOVQ AX, 0x8(DI)            
  main.go:10        0x44ce52        488b442430      MOVQ 0x30(SP), AX           
  main.go:10        0x44ce57        48894710        MOVQ AX, 0x10(DI)           
  main.go:10        0x44ce5b        8b052ff60600        MOVL runtime.writeBarrier(SB), AX   
  main.go:10        0x44ce61        85c0            TESTL AX, AX                
  main.go:10        0x44ce63        7517            JNE 0x44ce7c                
  main.go:10        0x44ce65        488b442420      MOVQ 0x20(SP), AX           
  main.go:10        0x44ce6a        488907          MOVQ AX, 0(DI)              
  main.go:16        0x44ce6d        48897c2438      MOVQ DI, 0x38(SP)           
  main.go:16        0x44ce72        488b6c2410      MOVQ 0x10(SP), BP           
  main.go:16        0x44ce77        4883c418        ADDQ $0x18, SP              
  main.go:16        0x44ce7b        c3          RET                 
  main.go:16        0x44ce7c        488b442420      MOVQ 0x20(SP), AX           
  main.go:10        0x44ce81        e86aaaffff      CALL runtime.gcWriteBarrier(SB)     
  main.go:10        0x44ce86        ebe5            JMP 0x44ce6d                
  main.go:10        0x44ce88        e85385ffff      CALL runtime.morestack_noctxt(SB)   
  main.go:10        0x44ce8d        eb81            JMP main.memAllocRepro(SB)      
  :-1           0x44ce8f        cc          INT $0x3
```

Disassemble of the memory pointed to by the RAX register:

```
(dlv) disassemble -a 0x0000000000455660 0x0000000000455860
        .:0     0x455660        1800                    sbb byte ptr [rax], al
        .:0     0x455662        0000                    add byte ptr [rax], al
        .:0     0x455664        0000                    add byte ptr [rax], al
        .:0     0x455666        0000                    add byte ptr [rax], al
        .:0     0x455668        0800                    or byte ptr [rax], al
        .:0     0x45566a        0000                    add byte ptr [rax], al
        .:0     0x45566c        0000                    add byte ptr [rax], al
        .:0     0x45566e        0000                    add byte ptr [rax], al
        .:0     0x455670        8e66f9                  mov fs, word ptr [rsi-0x7]
        .:0     0x455673        1b02                    sbb eax, dword ptr [rdx]
        .:0     0x455675        0808                    or byte ptr [rax], cl
        .:0     0x455677        17                      ?
        .:0     0x455678        60                      ?
        .:0     0x455679        0d4a000000              or eax, 0x4a
        .:0     0x45567e        0000                    add byte ptr [rax], al
        .:0     0x455680        c01f47                  rcr byte ptr [rdi], 0x47
        .:0     0x455683        0000                    add byte ptr [rax], al
        .:0     0x455685        0000                    add byte ptr [rax], al
        .:0     0x455687        0000                    add byte ptr [rax], al
        .:0     0x455689        0c00                    or al, 0x0
        .:0     0x45568b        004062                  add byte ptr [rax+0x62], al
        .:0     0x45568e        0000                    add byte ptr [rax], al
        .:0     0x455690        c0684500                shr byte ptr [rax+0x45], 0x0
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are asking, but have you tried collecting that return value in the noAlloc1 case when you return `&values` and using it somehow? The compiler is very efficient at discovering useless operations and optimizing. It's possible the for loop is confusing the compiler optimizations. In fact, have you checked to see if noAlloc1 (being a simple function) is simply being inlined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape analysis determines whether any references to a value escape the function in which the value is declared.

In Go, arguments are passed by value, typically on the stack; the stack is reclaimed at the end of the function. However, returning the reference `&values` from the `memAllocRepro` function gives the `values` parameter declared in `memAllocRepro` a lifetime beyond the end of the function. The `values` variable is moved to the heap.

`memAllocRepro`: `&values`: Alloc

```
./escape.go:3:6: cannot inline memAllocRepro: unhandled op FOR
./escape.go:7:9: &values escapes to heap
./escape.go:7:9:    from ~r1 (return) at ./escape.go:7:2
./escape.go:3:37: moved to heap: values
```

The `noAlloc1` function is inlined in the `main` function. The `values` argument, if necessary, is declared in and does not escape from the `main` function.

`noAlloc1`: `&values`: No Alloc

```
./escape.go:10:6: can inline noAlloc1 as: func([]int)*[]int{return &values}
./escape.go:23:10: inlining call to noAlloc1 func([]int)*[]int{return &values}
```

The `noAlloc2` function `values` argument is returned as `values`. `values` is returned on the stack. There is no reference to `values` in the `noAlloc2` function and so no escape.

`noAlloc2`: `values`: No Alloc

---

```
package main

func memAllocRepro(values []int) *[]int {
    for {
        break
    }
    return &values
}

func noAlloc1(values []int) *[]int {
    return &values
}

func noAlloc2(values []int) []int {
    for {
        break
    }
    return values
}

func main() {
    memAllocRepro(nil)
    noAlloc1(nil)
    noAlloc2(nil)
}
```

Output:

```
$ go build -a -gcflags='-m -m' escape.go
# command-line-arguments
./escape.go:3:6: cannot inline memAllocRepro: unhandled op FOR
./escape.go:10:6: can inline noAlloc1 as: func([]int) *[]int { return &values }
./escape.go:14:6: cannot inline noAlloc2: unhandled op FOR
./escape.go:21:6: cannot inline main: non-leaf function
./escape.go:23:10: inlining call to noAlloc1 func([]int) *[]int { return &values }
./escape.go:7:9: &values escapes to heap
./escape.go:7:9:    from ~r1 (return) at ./escape.go:7:2
./escape.go:3:37: moved to heap: values
./escape.go:11:9: &values escapes to heap
./escape.go:11:9:   from ~r1 (return) at ./escape.go:11:2
./escape.go:10:32: moved to heap: values
./escape.go:14:31: leaking param: values to result ~r1 level=0
./escape.go:14:31:  from ~r1 (return) at ./escape.go:18:2
./escape.go:23:10: main &values does not escape
$
```